# Issues with Samba Connection

Tags: networking, server, samba, file-sharing

So I'm building my first home server and am having issues with the samba system. All my computers can detect it but I am receiving errors telling me it is inaccessible. The computers in the house are both Windows and Linux. Here is my samba setup:

```bsh
bal]
    ; General server settings
    netbios name = FieldsVille
    server string =
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    announce version = 5.0
    socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_KEEPALIVE SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192

    passdb backend = tdbsam
    security = user
    null passwords = true
    username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
    name resolve order = hosts wins bcast

    wins support = yes

    printing = CUPS
    printcap name = CUPS

    syslog = 1
    syslog only = yes

; NOTE: If you need access to the user home directories uncomment the
; lines below and adjust the settings to your hearts content.
[homes]
    valid users = %S
    create mode = 0600
    directory mode = 0755
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
    veto files = /*.{*}/.*/mail/bin/

; NOTE: Only needed if you run samba as a primary domain controller.
; Not needed as this config doesn't cover that matter.
[netlogon]
    path = /var/lib/samba/netlogon
    admin users = Administrator
    valid users = %U
    read only = no

; NOTE: Again - only needed if you're running a primary domain controller.
[Profiles]
    path = /var/lib/samba/profiles
    valid users = %U
    create mode = 0600
    directory mode = 0700
    writeable = yes
    browseable = yes

; NOTE: Inside this place you may build a printer driver repository for
; Windows - I'll cover this topic in another HOWTO.
[print$]
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers
    browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = yes
    write list = root
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 0775

[printers]
    path = /tmp
   printable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    browseable = no

; Uncomment if you need to share your CD-/DVD-ROM Drive
;[DVD-ROM Drive]
    ;path = /media/cdrom
    ;browseable = yes
    ;read only = yes
    ;guest ok = yes

[MyFiles]
    path = /home/robert/main
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
    create mask = 0644
    directory mask = 0755
    force user = YOUR_USERNAME
    force group = YOUR_USERGROUP
```

Also does anyone know any other possible programs to set up the file sharing for the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you use real server or just install samba package in your desktop system ?
In my machine i added the samba configuration with this simple script :

> **[ISO_Linux]**
>
> **path = /home/teluk/iso**
>
> **guest ok = yes**
>
> **read only = no**
>
> **browseable = yes**

Make sure your directory permissions is set to accessible for everyone but don't set writable permissions . This example command to make your shared directory is accessible without writable  :

> **sudo chmod -R 755 /home/teluk/iso**

After that restart the smbd dan nmd with this command :

> **sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart && sudo /etc/init.d/nmbd restart**

If you use Ubuntu desktop with samba , open your file manager like nautilus , pcmanfm , thunar etc. Press ctrl+L and type this to check it:

> **smb://localhost**

if you done the shared directory is show up in your file manager , next you can try to access your samba in windows system with press windows_button+R then type //your_ip .

Good luck .

NB : "/home/teluk" is may home directory you can change that with your directory location .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using the default smb.conf that's configured for ease of setting up or not. I'd recommend doing that first for debugging.

You need to run `sudo smbpasswd -a <user>` for each user that needs to login as well (I usually have to anyway).

There should be a default `smb.conf` at `/usr/share/samba/smb.conf`